# Python: List directories/sub-directories with file names

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to list directories, sub-directories files by the time modified order. i am getting desired result with below code. But when put this code in function, i am getting only last line.

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root = 'Test\\inputs\\'
pattern = "*"

for path, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(root), reverse=True):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Output:

```
Test\inputs\backup\cdr_dsw
Test\inputs\backup\cdr_ds.xml
Test\inputs\backup\dsdf.xml
Test\inputs\testing.txt
```

`same code using function:`

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
root = 'Test\\inputs\\'
pattern = "*"

def Listdir():
    X = []
    for path, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(root), reverse=True):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch(name, pattern):
                X.append(os.path.join(path, name))
                return X

print(Listdir())
```

`output:`

```
Test\inputs\backup\cdr_dsw
```

Not sure what mistake i am doing. please help to correct my mistake. i want to use this as a function.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you write the `return X` into the `if` , it just return the first one ,
you can write it under the `for` , so you can return the X when all your path appended

```
def Listdir():
    X = []
    for path, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(root), reverse=True):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch(name, pattern):
                X.append(os.path.join(path, name))
     return X

print(Listdir())
```